# ARIMA Predicted values are blank

Tags: r, arima

I am implementing ARIMA for a simple ts data. but my end result on **fit 2** is **numeric(0)**. I don't understand where i'm wrong.

```
fit<-arima(diff(log(AirPassengers)), c(1,0,1),seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,1),Period=12))

fit1 <- predict(fit,n.ahead = 3*12)

fit2<- 2.718 ^ fit1$fit1
```

Comment: use fit2<- 2.718 ^ fit1$pred

Comment: Thank you very much :) Perfectly works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a mistake in fit1$fit1 , use fit1$pred instead

```
use fit2<- 2.718 ^ fit1$pred
```

and mark this as answered.

Comment: Hi This works perfectly. Yet my predicted graph is way of the actual values. Can you help me?  This is the code i use: acf(diff(log(citrixts)))
pacf(diff(log(citrixts)))
pred <-arima(log(citrixts), c(1,0,1), seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,1),Period=12))
pred1 <-predict (arima1,n.ahead = 3*12)
pred3 <- 2.178 ^ pred1$pred
data : year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

2015    19  14  9   7   16  28  23  33  42  38  35  82

2016    71  92  102 64  80  59  85  128 85  99  107 105

Comment: i can help you if you can provide reproducible example of your actual data using dput(), You can use Auto.arima , for the forecasting which is easy and fast.